# Showing Link in Text Field in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

In my Rails 3.1 app, I have a text field for comments and I want to be able to allow people to include clickable links (instead of just the url showing as plain text), as well as having the text field recognize when a user had line breaks in their text field (without the user adding html).  How can I do this?

This works for showing a link if a user puts the html for a href:
`<%= simple_format(@user.description) %>`

And this works for recognizing and displaying the line breaks from carriage returns in the text_field:
`<%= h(@user.description).gsub(/\n/, '<br/>').html_safe %>`

However, I haven't figured out how to do both, together.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about this?

```
#Doesnt work in this case
#<%= simple_format( h(@user.description).gsub(/\n/, '<br/>') ).html_safe %>
```

**EDIT:**
Seems like you need `auto_link` function to achieve this. Though it is removed from rails 3.1 it is available as a gem. So **if you are using rails 3.1 or later** you need to get this from a separate gem

```
#in Gemfile
gem "rails_autolink", "~> 1.0.9"
#in application.rb
require 'rails_autolink'

#Run
bundle install

#now in you view use it like
<%= h auto_link(simple_format(text)) %>
```

`auto_link` not only converts urls but also email addresses in clickable link. Get the document [here](http://rubydoc.info/gems/rails_autolink/1.0.9/frames).

Reference Links:

- http://rubygems.org/gems/rails_autolink
- http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/TextHelper/auto_link

Comment: it recognizes the line breaks, but doesn't turn the URL to a html link

Comment: I can't figure out where to put the "require 'rails_autolink' (so I get the error "cannot load such file -- rails_autolink").  I didn't have a application.rb model, but I tried creating one and that didn't work.  I also tried to put it in the application controller and model controller before the class started and after the class started and I still get the error.

Comment: See line 4 here https://gist.github.com/3695897. 
Explanation: `application.rb` is a config file. Find this in `RAILS_ROOT/config/application.rb`. Then, u need to make sure that the `rails_autolink` gem is installed in your system. So after adding the `require rails_autolink` in your `config/application.rb`, u need to run `bundle install`. You should find the name `rails_autolink` in the output of the command (`bundle install`).

Comment: Thank you, I got it to work.  The final code was `<%= h auto_link(@user.description).gsub(/\n/, '<br/>').html_safe %>`

Comment: Thats nice. but wouldnt it be better to use `simple_format` to convert your `\n` to `<br />`. Because it supports some more formatting also. However, use what fits to your requirement best.

Comment: Yes, but it didn't work when I put it as indicated.  It seemed to double the amount of line breaks so two would show instead of one.

Answer (score 0):

#### Use the Rinku Gem

[Link is here.](https://github.com/vmg/rinku)

It brilliantly solves the problem. Enjoy!