# Only allow links to display from user input

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, user-input

My Rails app allows users to post comments which are displayed with simple_format. Currently all html is escaped but I'd like for users to be able to post links in their comments. Looking at the rails_autolink gem discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12310798/showing-link-in-text-field-in-rails) I should be able to do this but I don't know if this is the best/safest method.

auto_link was removed from rails and the gem says

> This is an extraction of the `auto_link` method from rails. The `auto_link` method was removed from Rails in version Rails 3.1. **This gem is meant to bridge the gap for people migrating.**

How should I allow only links to be shown in my comments?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [Sanitize](https://github.com/rgrove/sanitize).

Tags and attributes (only the mentioned tags and attributes are allowed, nothing else).

```
<%= sanitize @article.body, tags: %w(a) %>
```

Here is the [documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/SanitizeHelper.html#method-i-sanitize).